# batch use set /p variable in tracert command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm making a program for my friend and he wants me to make a command that allows him to input a website and get IP adresses from it, so I'm trying to make a program that gets the ip from a set /p command and it doesn't really work.

```
@echo off
color 0a
title trace ipOnly
cls
echo enter ip or url to begin
echo.
set /p a = ip/url: 
tracert -d %a%
pause
```

Comment: Remove the spaces between assignment, `set /p a=ip/url: `

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
@echo off
color 0a
title trace ipOnly
cls
echo enter ip or url to begin
echo.
set /p "URL=ip/url : " 
tracert -d %URL%
pause
```